# How to avoid the NumberFormatException when using a DATETIME column in SQLite?

Tags: java, sqlite, jooq

I am using a SQLite database with tables that include DATETIME columns.  jOOQ default binds the DATETIME columns to java.sql.Timestamp.  Querying tables with DATETIME columns causes a NumberFormatException (handled) for each column.

I am using jOOQ 3.11.9.

The exception is thrown in the `org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.DefaultTimestampBinding` parse method when it first tries to convert the timestamp string value as a number.

```
private static final long parse(Class < ? extends java.util.Date > type, String date) throws SQLException {

    // Try reading a plain number first
    try {
        return Long.valueOf(date);
    }

    // If that fails, try reading a formatted date
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {

        // [#7325] In SQLite dates could be stored in both ISO standard formats:
        //         With T (default standard), or without T (optional standard, JDBC standard)
        date = StringUtils.replace(date, "T", " ");

        if (type == Timestamp.class)
            return Timestamp.valueOf(date).getTime();

        // Dates may come with " 00:00:00". This is safely trimming time information
        else if (type == Date.class)
            return Date.valueOf(date.split(" ")[0]).getTime();

        else if (type == Time.class)
            return Time.valueOf(date).getTime();

        throw new SQLException("Could not parse date " + date, e);
    }
}
```

Looking at the the `get0` and `set0` DefaultTimestampBinding methods the Timestamp is always get/set as a String.  Is there a reason why for SQLite this is not passed to the JDBC statement/result as a Timestamp?  Is there any way to override this behavior or avoid the exception?

```
Override
final void set0(BindingSetStatementContext < U > ctx, Timestamp value) throws SQLException {
    if (ctx.family() == SQLITE)
        ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), value.toString());
    else
        ctx.statement().setTimestamp(ctx.index(), value);
}

@Override
final Timestamp get0(BindingGetResultSetContext < U > ctx) throws SQLException {

    // SQLite's type affinity needs special care...
    if (ctx.family() == SQLDialect.SQLITE) {
        String timestamp = ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index());
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Timestamp(parse(Timestamp.class, timestamp));
    } else {
        return ctx.resultSet().getTimestamp(ctx.index());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could register a custom binding with the code generator, note that this issue will be addressed in the upcoming jOOQ 3.12 release as well as in the next 3.11 service release. See https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8736 for details.

Comment: Any idea why SQLite has a special check and conversion in the Timestamp binding versus just passing the Timestamp to the JDBC statement/result?

Comment: @MikeRuffing: It has been some time since the first implementation of SQLite support, but I think this is because of SQLite's type affinity and the related problems when reading dates in string format. I think the xerial JDBC driver simply cannot handle all the possible date formats, so in order to work around any possible limitations, we rolled our own.